# GameAnalytics ad events impression don't show in dashboard

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, gameanalytics

Ad dashboard shows 0 impressions even though the filters are being populated with placement names in the dashboard so events are getting to the server.

Using Unity SDK v.6.0.14 and building for iOS

sending Ad rewarded event as follows, "unknown" because I don't have ad network information:

```
GameAnalytics.NewAdEvent(GAAdAction.RewardReceived, GAAdType.RewardedVideo, "unknown", "adLocationName");
```

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out:
When the user received the reward I was sending "GAAdAction.RewardReceived" but not sending "GAAdAction.Show" any more, which still has to be sent.

So, even if the user receives the reward, "GAAdAction.Show" still has to be sent when the ad closes, which is a little counterintuitive.

After changing the implementation and sending both events impressions stats started showing up in the dashboard.